# how do i read this file user data

Tags: image, video, onedrive

how do i read this file?

```
14 00 08 00 00 00 0D 30 D5 4E 00 00 00 00 2A 01 00 00 2A 01 00 00 37 00 00 00 50 69 63 74 75 72 65 73 2F 52 65 73 74 6F 72 65 64 2F 50 69 63 74 75 72 65 73 2F 6E 6F 6D 6F 72 2F 33 44 20 4F 62 6A 65 63 74 73 2F 64 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 2E 69 6E 69 FF FE 0D 00 0A 00 5B 00 2E 00 53 00 68 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 43 00 6C 00 61 00 73 00 73 00 49 00 6E 00 66 00 6F 00 5D 00 0D 00 0A 00 4C 00 6F 00 63 00 61 00 6C 00 69 00 7A 00 65 00 64 00 52 00 65 00 73 00 6F 00 75 00 72 00 63 00 65 00 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 3D 00 40 00 25 00 53 00 79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00 6D 00 52 00 6F 00 6F 00 74 00 25 00 5C 00 73 00 79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00 6D 00 33 00 32 00 5C 00 77 00 69 00 6E 00 64 00 6F 00 77 00 73 00 2E 00 73 00 74 00 6F 00 72 00 61 00 67 00 65 00 2E 00 64 00 6C 00 6C 00 2C 00 2D 00 32 00 31 00 38 00 32 00 35 00 0D 00 0A 00 49 00 63 00 6F 00 6E 00 52 00 65 00 73 00 6F 00 75 00 72 00 63 00 65 00 3D 00 25 00 53 00 79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00 6D 00 52 00 6F 00 6F 00 74 00 25 00 5C 00 73 00 79 00 73 00 74 00 65 00 6D 00 33 00 32 00 5C 00 69 00 6D 00 61 00 67 00 65 00 72 00 65 00 73 00 2E 00 64 00 6C 00 6C 00 2C 00 2D 00 31 00 39 00 38 00 0D 00 0A 00 50 4B 07 08 90 4D F9 6E 2A 01 00 00 2A 01 00 00 50 4B 03 04 14 00 08 00 00 00 0D 30 D5 4E 00 00 00 00 153 01 00 00 153 01 00 00 35 00 00 00 50 69 63 74 75 72 65 73 2F 52 65 73 74 6F 72 65 64 2F 50 69 63 74 75 72 65 73 2F 6E 6F 6D 6F 72 2F 43 6F 6E 74 61 63 74 73 2F 64 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 2E 69 6E 69 FF FE 0D 00 0A 00 5B 00 2E 00 53 00 68 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 43 00 6C 00 61 00 73 00 73 00 49 00 6E 00 66 00 6F 00 5D 00 0D 00 0A 00 4C 00 6F 00 63 00 61 00 6C 00 69 00 7A 00 65 00 64 00 52 00 65 00 73 00 6F 00 75 00 72 00 63 00 65 00 4E 00 61 00 6D 00 65 00 3D 00 40 00 25 00 43 00 6F 00 6D 00 6D 00 6F 00 6E 00 50 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 61 00 6D 00 46 00 69 00 6C##
```

Answer (score 0):

It is encoded in hexadecimal.

You could use for example an online converter to display the text.

[Convert hexadecimal to text](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/)